# Which one is finer: standard topology or upper limit topology?

Tags: general-topology

Out of these two which one is finer over $\mathbb{R}$?

- Standard topology
- Upper limit topology

Answer (score 5):

The upper limit topology is finer. Notice that in the upper limit topology,\begin{equation*}
 (a,b) =\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left(a,b-\frac{1}{n}\right].
\end{equation*}
Hence every open interval in the standard topology is also open in the upper limit topology, but something like $(c,d]$ is not open in the standard topology.
I hope this makes sense.

Comment: I think you mean $b-\frac 1n$.

Comment: Yup! Thank you - editing now.