# Show that a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is compact in upper limit topology

Tags: general-topology, compactness, sorgenfrey-line

I want to show that $A = [0,1]$ is not a compact subspace of $\mathbb{R}$, where $\mathbb{R}$ has the upper limit topology with open sets of the form $(a,b] = \{x \in \mathbb{R}\space|\space a < x \leq b\}$.

I read a suggested solution which confused me. It said that with the open cover $\mathcal{A} = \{(r, 1] \space | \space 0 < r \leq 1 \} \cup (-1,1]$ of $A$, there is a finite subcover that does not cover $A$. I understand that this is the case, but not why that would prove that $[0,1]$ is not compact. As far as I know every open covering should have *a* finite subcollection covering $A$. Not that every finite subcollection must cover $A$. If someone would like to clarify this, I would be very greatful.

Some suggestions on how to prove the statement that $A$ is not compact under this topology would also be helpful. I find compactness to be a confusing subject, to say the least...

Comment: The phrase "there is a finite subcover that does not cover" sound confused to me. Also, in your cover, don't you mean $(-1,0]$ instead of $(-1,1]$, for otherwise $\{(-1,1]\}$ is a finite subcover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a topological space $X$ with a topology $\tau$ a subset $A\subset X$ is called compact in $X$ if and only if each open cover $\mathcal{A}\subset \tau$ of $A$ has a finite cover $\mathcal{B}\subset\mathcal{A}$ of $A$.

The solution you get is wrong and doesn't prove that $A=[0,1]$ is not compact in the upper limit topology of $\mathbb{R}$. Either the example of José do it or you can fix your solution if you consider
$$
\mathcal{A}=\{(r,1]~:~0<r<1\}\cup(-1,0].
$$
You get $\bigcup_{I\in\mathcal{A}}I=(-1,1]\supset A$.
But for each finite subset of $\mathcal{B}\subset\mathcal{A}$ you get either $$
\bigcup_{I\in\mathcal{B}}I=(-1,0]\cup(\tilde{r},1]\not\supset[0,1]=A
$$ 
or 
$$
\bigcup_{I\in\mathcal{B}}I=(\tilde{r},1]\not\supset[0,1]=A
$$ 
where $\tilde{r}=\min\{r\in(0,1)~:~(r,1]\in\mathcal{B}\}>0$ is well defined since $\mathcal{B}$ is finite. This proves that $A=[0,1]$ is not compact in the upper limit topology.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand that remark. But you can prove that $(0,1]$ is not compact using the open cover$$(-1,0]\cup\left(\frac12,1\right]\cup\left(\frac13,\frac12\right]\cup\left(\frac14,\frac13\right]\cup\cdots$$Since it is a disjoint union, there no subcovers other than the original one.

Comment: wouldnt that prove it is not compact?

Comment: That is what I wanted to prove.

Comment: I can't upvote yet. Both this and the answer by Mundron Schmidt was very helpful and clear!

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to the lower limit topology version:

[GRE9367 #62](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2970426)

> [image]

[Ian Coley](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~iacoley/gre/Practice%203%20solutions.pdf)'s solution:

> [image]

[Sean Sovine](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4qQg_AuKUglY0I1bkZ5azl6NDQ/view)'s solution:

> [image]

---

To prove $X$ is not compact, my first proof was similar to Ian Coley's, but I came up with another proof:

> If $X$ is compact, then because $X$ is Hausdorff, $X$ is compact Hausdorff in both standard and lower limit topologies of $\mathbb R$. This implies that the topologies are equal by (1), a contradiction.

Here we have:

> If $X$ is compact, then because $X$ is Hausdorff, $X$ is compact Hausdorff in both standard and **upper** limit topologies of $\mathbb R$. This implies that the topologies are equal by (1) and (2), a contradiction.

---

(1) Munkres Exer26.1 ([dbfin pf](https://dbfin.com/topology/munkres/chapter-3/section-26-compact-spaces/problem-1-solution/))

> [image]

(2) [Which one is finer: standard topology or upper limit topology?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1243544/) Both upper limit and lower limit topologies are finer than standard topology.